# morgan deprecated default format: use combined format

Tags: node.js, morgan

I am using `morgan` package in my application in nodejs to log HTTP request but I am getting this warning. How can it be resolved?

**morgan deprecated default format: use combined format app.js:10:9**

Comment: `journalctl -u mysql.service -n 30`

Comment: look into the error log of mysql that shows you exactly what is wrong. it can also be a system problem, but the3 frist look is always mysql error log

Comment: xampp will install mysql! Why you try to install it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const morgan = require("morgan");
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
```

Make sure you're not calling `app.use(morgan)` anywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2021

I also got some trouble with this warning. I configured my app for ES6 syntax support with `esm` package. But morgan doesn't like ES6 import syntax.

It will give you a deprecated warning if you use import syntaxt. like,

wrong: `import morgan from 'morgan'`

right: `const morgan = require('morgan')`

to avoid deprecated warning use regular require syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript, you must install this package that contains the type definition of morgan:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/morgan

Then change your import to

```
import * as morgan from 'morgan';
```

and the error will be gone